# Determing iPad orientation on startup

Tags: objective-c, ipad, orientation

how come when i use the following method in didLoad or willAppear with the iPad simulator the device always thinks its in landscape mode when its clearly in portrait.

```
UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];    
NSLog(@"orientation - %i", UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(orientation));
```

this works fine in the iPhone simulator, is there another way to find out the devices orientation?

I have tried adding the supported orientations in the app.plist, but still the simulator thinks its in landscape mode?

Cheers,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[UIDeviceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDevice_Class/Reference/UIDevice.html) is not the same thing as [UIInterfaceOrientation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIApplication_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Try something like `[[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` instead.